# What's wrong with my cron command?

Tags: ssh, cron, cpanel

I'm running cron from cpanel, i want to run one file and when it is finish the next one. this is my command

```
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null https://example.com/file.php > /dev/null 2>&1 && wget -q -O - https://example.com/file2.php
```

It runs only the first one.
Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the first command doesn't fail? The second `wget` is invoked without its full path. It shouldn't be a problem with the default `PATH` which should be `"/usr/bin:/bin"` but make sure you don't overwrite it in your `crontab`. Note this doesn't work in `crontab` as you might expect: `PATH=/some/other/path:$PATH` because `$PATH` is not expanded there. So if you use such a clause you will have unexpected `PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

`&&` only runs the second command if the first command exits with a zero (no error) exit code. Maybe `wget` couldn't fetch the URL you specified?

If you want the second command to always be run after the first command even if the first command reports errors, then use `;` instead of `&&` to join the two commands.